# When POST has Id in the URI - should Id also be in Body Model Parameters? Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a ViewModel used in a Web API web service.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have an ApiController with a method like this:

```
[Route("api/Customer/{Id}")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(int Id, [FromBody]Customer Customer)
{
    ...Add to db, Id also exists in Customer
    return Ok();
}
```

Customer Id is available in the URI - but the Customer object contains a Customer Id - which could be passed into the Post.

This seems to be redundant - and may lead to the Id being put in the wrong place.

What is best practice? If I need to remove Id from Customer body how do I do it?

Reference - "Using HTTP Verbs with the Task Resource" - level 2 in the REST Maturity Model - states the Id should be passed in the URI for updating or inserting tasks with an Id: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generally we call a **POST** method when we try to create a **new record**, in your case "Customer" and **PUT** method to **update** an existing record. But that is not mandatory. You can create and update an existing record by using POST method too.

In general, we set **auto generated field** to the Id (primary key) field of a table. That means, we don't need to pass data for Id field when we try to add a record. In that case you don't need to pass Id in your URI and you don't need to write a parameter for Id in your API POST method.

So your ajax method will be like this bellow,

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'myURL',
      type: "json",
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      data: myFormData,
      success: function(data)
        {
         alert("success");
        }
       })
```

As I mentioned above you can use the same method (POST) for add a new record or edit an existing record, so how is that possible ?

I assume you are passing Id value in your ajax code in **data** parameter.

So your API Post method will be like this,

```
[Route("api/Customer")] // I removed Id here
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Customer Customer)
{
   if(Customer!=null && Customer.Id==0) //You can check Id with null value
    {
     // Add a new record to Customer
    }
   else
    {
     // fetch Customer data by Customer.Id and update here
    }
   return Ok();
}
```

As simple as that. But yes, you can write this update code in a PUT method.

But if you are passing value to the Id field(that is not auto generated field) in POST method, then also you can **remove the Id parameter** from your POST method and your Route will be like this,

```
[Route("api/Customer")]
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: In my case to elaborate - the call to the API may be to update an existing record OR insert a new one with the passed ID. Hence the PUT. In both cases I need the ID from the caller - I can't auto-generate.

Comment: You can use the same as i stated above. No need to write a parameter int Id, as you are passing it with your FormBody. Change the Route attribute as I mentioned.

Comment: I have inserted a grid from the Rest Maturity Model to elaborate why I need an Id in the URI

Comment: Then where is the issue ? You have written correctly. You already have Id in FromBody Customer. You can Add/Update with the customer.Id. And int id parameter will be as it is, nothing to do with that. Because it is same as customer.Id.

Comment: no Id is read from the URI specifically - go to PUT > (Element URI). Id should be in the URI not body.